# Countable Set, the numbers rational

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Good morning, i want to try solving this exercise:

Prove $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable set.

I make this:

$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$

Be q $∈$ $\mathbb{Q}$, if $q>0$ then:

$f\left(n\right)=\frac{t}{n}\:t,n\,\epsilon\mathbb{N}$

$f(n)$ is biyective.

Be q $∈$ $\mathbb{Q}$, if $q<0$ then:

$f(n)=\frac{t}{-n}\:t,n\,\epsilon\mathbb{N}$

$f(n)$ is biyective.

Then, $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable set.

It's good?

Comment: 1) You never used 2) You never defined t. 3) Your function is not surjective. 4) There is no reason to split up your argument into cases if both cases have the exact same content. 5) It's not good.

Comment: Is t/n and t/-n supposed to equal q?  How do you determine whether f(8) = 1/8,  -2/8, 7/8, or 49/8.  If f(n) = 1/64 and f(m) = 3/64 is f really 1 to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your proof is not correct.

Here are some food for thought to prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

1. Try to prove that the following map is injective: $$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}\mathbb{N}^2&\rightarrow&\mathbb{N}\\(m,n)&\mapsto & 2^m3^n\end{array}\right..$$
2. Can you find an injection of $\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{N}$?
3. Can you deduce from there an injection of $\mathbb{Q}$ into $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Thanks Falcon, but i don't understand why my function is not surjective? Thanks

Comment: Defining your function $f$, you use an integer $t$ you have never defined. What do you mean by this $t$?

Comment: You don't *have* a function. f(n) = t/n is not a function as it has many values and there is no way determine if f(5) = 1/5 or 2/5 or 479/5 or -18/5. It's not surjective because if f(n) = 275/694 what is n? If f(m) =273/694 what is m? It's not injective because if f(n) = 7/6 = 14/12 and f(m) = 5/6 = 10/12 what is m?  Your function doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Falcon i was working in this, and i prove Z have a biyection with Q, and how Z have a biyection with N now i can say N have a biyection with Q and Q is countable set?